# Two posts in same div - WP loop

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I would need the following in Wordpress:

```
<div class="posts-wrapped">
    <div id="post-1" class="post">
        <h1>Title 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="post-2" class="post">
        <h1>Title 2</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="posts-wrapped">
    <div id="post-3" class="post">
        <h1>Title 3</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="post-4" class="post">
        <h1>Title 4</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know how to get posts with WP loop, but how can I wrap every two posts in .posts-wrapped div?

I fetch the posts with WP_Query.

Thanks!

EDIT:
So I tried few ways to do it. For example with this:

```
$index=0;
<div class="posts-wrapped">

<?php
while ( have_posts() ) {
    $index++;   
?>
<div class="post">
        <h1><?php the_post(); ?></h1>
    </div> <?php
if(($index % 2) ==0){
echo '</div><div class="posts-wrapped">';
}
} ?>

</div>
```

But this prints one extra empty posts-wrapped div:

```
<div class="posts-wrapped">
    Lorem ipsum 1<br>
    Lorem 2 ipsum est<br>
</div>
<div class="posts-wrapped">
    Lorem ipsum 1<br>
    Lorem 2 ipsum est<br>
</div>
<div class="posts-wrapped">
</div>
```

How can i get rid of this last empty div? It screws my carousel (this content is part of carousel).

Comment: You'll likely get a better answer at wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Oh, I'll added the question there too. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I didn't phrase my comment correctly. Wordpress.stackexchange "specializes" in your kind of question. This site has wordpress experts (as you see already from the answers you have) but there are *all* kinds of programming questions here. So, if your question "gets lost" in here, try the other site. I did not mean to say that you wouldn't get good answers here.

Answer (score 1):

Get the index that counts the loop iteration and check the modulus operation to know that its even or odd

```
$index=0;
<div class="posts-wrapped">

<?php
while ( have_posts() ) {
    $index++;   
?>
<div class="post">
        <h1><?php the_post(); ?></h1>
    </div> <?php
if(($index % 2) ==0){
echo '</div><div class="posts-wrapped">';
}
} ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
<?php
while(have_posts()){
    the_post();
?>
<div class="posts-wrapped">
    <div class="post">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </div>

    <?php
    if(have_posts()){ //Makes sure you have another post
        the_post();
    ?>
        <div class="post">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$i = 0;
if (have_posts()) : 
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    if($i == 0) {
        echo '<div class="posts-wrapped">';
    } ?>

    <div class="post">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </div>

<?php
$i++;
if($i == 2) {
    $i = 0;
    echo '</div>';
}

endwhile; 

if($i > 0) {
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Would you please try above code?